# Fire remember me cookie only when user clicks checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Updated Code: thank you for the suggestions so far. Still not working.

I'm trying to add a remember me cookie, but only when the user actually clicks the checkbox.  Is this possible?  I'm not having any luck with this code.  The cookie fires regardless if the checkbox is clicked or not:

```
JavaScript:
    <script>  
        $('#rememberme').click(function() {

        if ($('#rememberme').is(':checked')) {
            document.cookie="rememberme=yes;domain=.abc.com;path=/"
        localStorage.usrname = $('#username').val();
            localStorage.pass = $('#password').val(); localStorage.chkbx = $('#rememberme').val();
        } 
    else {
            document.cookie="rememberme=no;domain=.abc.com;path=/"
            localStorage.usrname = '';
        localStorage.pass = '';
        localStorage.chkbx = '';
    }
    });
</script>

HTML:
<label class="checkbox" style="border: none;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="rememberme" id="rememberme"> Remember me
</label>
```

Comment: For some reason it won't post the HTML or javascript as javascript code.  But if anyone has a working example of how this can be done any reference would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You need to fix brackets in the code.

Comment: After removing the last ```});``` and the changing the ```}``` after the if statement to a ```{``` everything should work.

Comment: The bracket after the IF statement is a "{" ??

Answer (score 1):

Updated Code

```
$('#rememberme').click(function() {
    if ($('#rememberme').is(':checked')){

  document.cookie = "rememberme=yes;domain=.abc.com;path=/"
  // save username and password
  localStorage.usrname = $('#username').val(); localStorage.pass = $('#pass').val(); localStorage.chkbx = $('#rememberme').val();
}
else {
  document.cookie = "rememberme=no;domain=.abc.com;path=/"
  localStorage.usrname = '';
  localStorage.pass = '';
  localStorage.chkbx = '';
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't working when you run the snipet

Answer (score 1):

tested below code in jsfiddle, hope it works as per your need. Please test it once, and let me know if its working as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/arivua/xpvt214o/924480/

```
// set cookie value
function setCookie(key, value) {
  document.cookie = key +"="+ escape(value) +
    ";domain="+ window.location.hostname +
    ";path=/";
}
// delete cookie
function deleteCookie(name) {
  setCookie(name, "");
}

var remember_me_check_box = $("#rememberme")
// handle click and manage cookie
remember_me_check_box.on("click", function(){
  if (remember_me_check_box.is(':checked')) {
    deleteCookie('rememberme');
    setCookie('rememberme', 'yes');
  } else {
    deleteCookie('rememberme');
    setCookie('rememberme', 'no');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this! In order to test successfully, should I see the cookie fired in the web browser console upon clicking the check box?

Comment: @Reading_code when you run the fiddle in chrome, you can see cookies for the domain `fiddle.shell.net`.. Use developer tools -> Application -> cookies -> select fiddle.shell.net you can see all the cookies for that domain.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to just set "If" and "else" conditions around the URL that declares rememeberme.  However the conditional URL is constructed (notice yes vs no) is handled by the back end folks where I am a front end UI developer.

```
<script>  
    $('#rememberme').click(function() {

    if ($('#rememberme').is(':checked')) {
        document.cookie="rememberme=yes;domain=.abc.com;path=/";
    } 
else {
        document.cookie="rememberme=no;domain=.abc.com;path=/";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          $('#rememberme').click(function () {
                  if ($('#rememberme').is(':checked')) {
                    document.cookie = "rememberme=yes;path=http://localhost:3000/login/"
                    var u = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var p = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    var r = document.getElementById('rememberme').value;
        
                    document.cookie = "email=" + u + ";path=http://localhost:3000/login/";
                    document.cookie = "password=" + p + ";path=http://localhost:3000/login/";
                  }
                  else {
                    document.cookie = "rememberme=no;path=http://localhost:3000/login/"
                    document.cookie = "email=;path=http://localhost:3000/login/";
                    document.cookie = "password=;path=http://localhost:3000/login/";
        
                  }
            });
    
     function getcookiedata() {
            var user = getCookie('email');
            var pswd = getCookie('password');
            var remember = getCookie('rememberme');
    
            document.getElementById('email').value = user;
            document.getElementById('password').value = pswd;
            if (remember == 'yes') {
              document.getElementById('rememberme').checked = true;
            } else {
              document.getElementById('rememberme').checked = false;
            }
        }

function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
        }
        return "";
    }






   <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme">&nbsp Remember Me<br>
```